# Can we use same domain for two applications in IIS 7.5?

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I have an old website with a domain name like example.org which was built in vb-script . Now, some part of the website is not working properly. We built that not functioning part of the website using ASP.NET MVC like a new application. How can I merge these two applications.

Comment: You can create an application (say mvcapp) under your IIS website with an application pool which will have integrated pipeline mode and .NET CLR version 4.0. Then you can browse to MVC application using url `example.org/mvcapp`

Comment: Maybe add a (sub) application underneath the main virtual directory? There are probably many ways of achieving what you want but without more detail on your circumstances it may be difficult to recommend a solution.

Comment: This has been asked multiple times before and answered multiple times before, please search before posting.